# Check from Client if NFS is running on Server

Tags: centos, mount, nfs

(my systems are running centos7)

I'm trying to check from the client if drives are mounted properly over NFS.

Typing the command `nfsstat -m` gives me the mounts that it thinks are currently mounted, but this is no guarantee that those folders are accessible. It could just be that the NFS server was running when those folders were mounted but that the NFS server is down now.

For example, if the NFS server goes down and on the client machine I type `df -h` then the command will hang indefinitely. Likewise, if I try to `ls` the folder I'm trying to mount then it too will hang indefinitely.

Here's an example that shows my problem

```
# on server
systemctl start nfs-server

# on client
mount node1:/mnt/images /mnt/images
df -h #works fine here

# on server
systemctl stop nfs-server

# on client
nfsstat -m #shows the list of nfs mounts
df -h #this command will hang
ls /mnt/images #this command will hang
```

Any suggestions on how to test if **from the client side** if the NFS server is running or if the NFS mounted folders are accessible would be greatly appreciated.

If I run `showmount -e` on the server I get this output (note `/mnt/images` and `/mnt/rv_output` and `/rv` are all folders I'm trying to mount from my client machines)

```
/mnt/rv_output 192.168.81.0/24
/mnt/images    192.168.81.0/24
/rv            192.168.81.0/24
```

But I'm not interested in testing this connection on the Server, I want to test it on the client machines. If I run `showmount -e` on the client I get the same output irregardless of whether the nfs-server has been activated from the Server computer.

```
clin_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Unable to receive: errno 111 (connection refused)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a standard setup, the NFS daemon on the server will be listening on TCP/UDP port 2049, so you can try to connect to it using `netcat`, `ncat`, `nc` or even `telnet`.  I'm not running CentOS, so I can't tell exactly what you have available, but on my machine (OpenBSD)

```
$ nc -z ip_of_nfs_server 2049
```

does the trick (add `-u` for UDP, the `-z` switch tells it to check for listening daemons without sending data).  Check the `man` pages for what you have on your machine to achieve the same with other tools. `telnet` is more or less ubiquitous so

```
$ telnet ip_of_nfs_server 2049
```

should also work (exit with `Ctrl+c`).

Answer (score 1):

### showmount

from `man showmount`

> showmount - show mount information for an NFS server

I use with `--exports` ( or `-e` ) option to see what is actually exported.

Comment: This didn't help as it displays the same result on the Client machines whether the NFS-server was running or not on the Server machine. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know `df -h` does what you need, but hangs, you can prepend your command with `timeout` command so it won't hang:

```bash
timeout 5s df -h 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null && echo OK || echo NOK
```